# how to define column definitions in a grid?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, datagrid

i have a grid with fixed number of rows but the columns are not fixed. So how do i set the column definitions.Is there any way to write it in xaml?

Answer (score 2):

You have both rows definition and columns definition:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid
```